# How to display the distance of all the sides of polygon on google maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I want to display the length of all the sides of polygon made on google maps. And maybe possibly print the area of the polygon at the center of the polygon

this is the code for displaying the length of polygon, but i can't seem to get the distance from the first and last point

```
private void polygonLabels() {
        int startIndex = polygonMarkers.size();

        for (int i = startIndex + 1; i < polygonPoints.size(); i++) {
            LatLng startPoint = polygonPoints.get(i - 1);
            LatLng endPoint = polygonPoints.get(i % polygonPoints.size());

            double distance = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(startPoint, endPoint);
            int distanceInt = (int) distance;
            String distanceString = distanceInt + "m";

            LatLng midpoint = SphericalUtil.interpolate(startPoint, endPoint, 0.5);

            if (i < polygonMarkers.size()) {
                Marker marker = polygonMarkers.get(i);
                TextView textView = (TextView) marker.getTag();
                textView.setText(distanceString);
            } else {
                Marker marker = addText(getApplicationContext(), mMap, midpoint, distanceString, 2, 18);
                polygonMarkers.add(marker);
            }
        }
    }
  public Marker addText(final Context context, final GoogleMap map, final LatLng location, final String text, final int padding, final int fontSize) {
        Marker marker = null;

        if (context == null || map == null || location == null || text == null
                || fontSize <= 0) {
            return marker;
        }

        final TextView textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setText(text);
        textView.setTextSize(fontSize);

        final Paint paintText = textView.getPaint();

        final Rect boundsText = new Rect();
        paintText.getTextBounds(text, 0, textView.length(), boundsText);
        paintText.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

        final Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        final Bitmap bmpText = Bitmap.createBitmap(boundsText.width() + 2 * padding,
                boundsText.height() + 2 * padding, conf);

        final Canvas canvasText = new Canvas(bmpText);
        paintText.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        canvasText.drawText(text, bmpText.getWidth() / 2f, bmpText.getHeight() / 2f - boundsText.exactCenterY(), paintText);


        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(location)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmpText))
                .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f);

        marker = map.addMarker(markerOptions);

        marker.setTag(textView);

        return marker;
    }
```

[Image of what this code displays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCtNE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Replace in the third line

```
i < polygonPoints.size();
```

with

```
i <= polygonPoints.size();
```

Furthermore, if you set in line 2 `startIndex = polygonMarkers.size()`, then in the for loop the condition `if (i < polygonMarkers.size())` is **always** false, you can omit this case.

If you want to calculate the area of the polygon, you have to implement the Shoelace formula, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula) (it is identical to the Triangle formula there). This formula calculates the area of a **plane** polygon, but if the side lengths are ~50km long as in your example, the difference is small. For an exact area value you need the Todhunter formula, see again [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry#Area_and_spherical_excess).